# Expose only field subset in REST JSON Service. Play framework, scala

Tags: json, scala, rest, playframework

I have scala REST service based on JSON and play framework. I have User case class

```
case class User(_id: BSONObjectID, username: String,password: String,creationTime: org.joda.time.DateTime)
```

and

```
object User{
val userReads: Reads[User] = (
(JsPath \ "username").read[String] (minLength[String](4) keepAnd maxLength[String] (32) ) and
(JsPath \ "password").read[String] (minLength[String](8) keepAnd maxLength[String] (32) ) 
?????)(User.apply _)

val userWrites: Writes[User] = ....
implicit val userFormat: Format[User] = Format (userReads, userWrites)
}
```

During registration (via REST API) I need to validate incoming json. I need only username and password and I don't need _id,creationTime etc. How to write properly Reads,Writes to validate only subset of the fields (please finish Reads and replase "?????" on your code)?

Comment: Since they are not options I think you will need to supply these values to create an instance of your exiting class. At any other point in time does your front end ever need the creation time/mongo id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a separate `class`, let's say a `RegistrationUser` and define JSON Reads and Writes for this `class`:

```
 case class RegistrationUser(userName: String, password: String)
```

In DB layer you can have a class like this:

```
 case class DbUser(_id: BSONObjectID,
                   username: String,
                   password: String,
                   creationTime: org.joda.time.DateTime)
```

And then you can map between these classes like this:

```
 def saveUserToDb(registrationUser: RegistrationUser): Unit = {
   val dbUser = DbUser(
     _id          = BSONObjectID.generate,
     username     = registrationUser.username,
     password     = registrationUser.password,
     creationTime = DateTime.now
   )

   // Now you have your DbUser and you can save it to Mongo as you did before
 }
```

You don't have to use the same model all over your application. It's perfectly valid to have separate models for individual layers - UI, service, database, ...

Comment: thank you for the good answer. How to avoid duplication of the fields in the case class? eg DbUser will contain username and password too

Comment: I wouldn't worry about this. Technically you could create a `trait` which contains these fields and both case classes would extend this trait, but I don't see any reason. Sometimes it is good to have loose coupling. If you change one (DB) model, it doesn't change the other (UI) model.

Comment: Thank you @Rado Buransky. I'm new to these technologies. So I have 2 model classes: RegistrationUser and DbUser (full set of the fields inc id and creationTime). How to transform RegistrationUser to DbUser and assign id,creationTime to save into DB. please some  code